# I can't create a splash screen for a Flutter app, using Xcode for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, splash-screen

I read lots of articles about the *Splash Screen* and how to create it in *Flutter* but almost all of them are deprecated now. Neither one worked for me, and I did try by myself, but the *Splash Screen* is not displaying, instead is displaying a white background.

I found out a package which could make my life easier, but I think it's better to create the *Splash Screen* as it is created from the official documentation.

As I understood, I opened the *Runner.xcworkspace* folder in *Xcode*. After that I uploaded *1x*, *2x*, *3x* images which were the logo with transparent background. (I used the same size)
I didn't find the real sizes for *1x*, *2x*, *3x* images anywhere for 2021/2022. A few people put there full images, while the others put only the logo.

[image]

I decided to change the background color from the *View* property as in the image below and I've fixed the image with the drag option and I am pretty sure that it's not a good approach.

[image]

So, even if I created somehow the *Splash Screen*, it is not rendered on the devices. I restarted the emulator, deleted the app and didn't work for me.

The question is, how to create *Splash Screen* for iOS in a correct way and why it is still a white background?

[image]

**Edit: I managed to display the *Splash Screen* selecting this property in the image above, but as I expected, it is not rendered well. So the question remains: how to create *Splash Screen* for iOS in a correct way?**

**Edit 2: The logo is now centered by autoresizing arrows from *Size Inspector*, but after 1 second it is resizing between 1x, 2x, 3x. Also, I used 3 constraints.**

Answer (score 0):

Chose your logo and click here:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrw8n.png)

Use alignment constants and set your logo 0 horizontally and 0 vertically. (Be sure you have chosen your logo file). Click "Add 2 Constants" It will show your logo in a centre at every Apple device.

Comment: It's not working to set any value to the constraints. Also, I should choose a logo with the same size for 1x, 2x, 3x with high resolution? It is ok? I managed to put in the centre by setting the arrows from the autoresizing, but after 1 second, the splash screen is changing with another one with other size.

Comment: I managed to set the constraints, after adding the constraints it is centered and it is resizing, but after 1 second it is changing.